# VIM highlight #IFDEF an #IF statements

Tags: vim

Is it possible to highlight #DEFINE statements in VIM.

VIM does manages to color correctly `#if 0`, but not more complex expressions. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to fix the colors for the 2nd one? I am working on a code base with lots of defined, and it's really hard to read without correct highlighting.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show code as literal text and the file type to highlight?

Comment: I want that in the case of this code:
    `#define AAA`

    `#ifndef AAA`
    `int x;`
    `#endif`

the `int x` would have a different color then if it was outside the block

Answer (score 2):

One of the very first Vim plugins published on [vim.org](https://www.vim.org/) is the [ifdef plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=7).

It provides highlighting for  `#ifdef  #ifndef  #else  #endif`  blocks (but not `#if defined()`), with the ability to mark a symbol as defined or undefined.

Comment: I already found and install it, but I doesn't seem to work for me. (VIM doesn't recognize  `:Define`)

Comment: @user1637056 there is a bit of documentation in [syntax/ifdef.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/ifdef-highlighting/blob/master/syntax/ifdef.vim#L13):

" Usage:
" Use as a syntax plugin (source ifdef.vim from ~/vimfiles/after/syntax/cpp.vim -
" also c.vim and idl.vim )

Answer (score 1):

You can override a color with the `highlight` command. Create the file `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim` and add the following line:

```
highlight cDefine ctermfg=4 cterm=bold
```

It will set the `define` instructions in bold light blue.

Also, this can help you choose a color: https://github.com/guns/xterm-color-table.vim

Comment: Thanks, but it does not answer my question. This makes the `#define AAA` colored in a different color.
What I want, is to have `int x` in a different color

Comment: Ah, I see. I would say it is not detectable by the editor. The `#define` line is completely independent with the following `#ifdef`, it could be anywhere else before, even in a separate file. The line `#if 0` can clearly be analysed as a non-accessible block, but I'd say the `#ifdef` you want to color can not be as easily analysed by Vim, you'd need the compiler for that. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand it could be hard for VIM to detect this automatically, but it does somehow manage to evaluate the expression correctly if I do [i.
Regardless, since the goal is code readability, I would be fine even with telling VIM the values of the defines manually, or even to color specific blocks with comment colors

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me. It does not color code in comment colors, but it hides it.
If I put the cursor on the AAA, in the line of `#ifdef AAA`, and type `[i`, VIM is able to show me the definition of AAA.
Then I look at the definition, and decide weather this code block should be displayed or not, and fold it using `zf%` (`zf` if fold, and `%` specifies to fold until the end of the block)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LSP. See [this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/clangd/clangd/discussions/1817).